# How to create a gnosis safe using the gnosis smart contracts and ethers.js?

Tags: web3js, ethers.js, gnosis-safe, gnosis

I'm trying to create a gnosis safe using ethers.js and gnosis smart contract but when I see the GnosisSafe Smart Contract(https://etherscan.io/address/0xd9Db270c1B5E3Bd161E8c8503c55cEABeE709552#code) I cannot find any relevant method to create a safe.Could someone please help me out with this.Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the proxy factory contract. Available deployments are in https://github.com/gnosis/safe-deployments/tree/main/src/assets/v1.3.0